# Synchronize MySql tables between servers

Tags: mysql, synchronization, master-slave

I'm looking for some help concerning pt-table-sync.

I have a Master-to-Master environment where Master1 is the master and Master2 is the fake slave. I have a situation where my fake slave has all new data because of a sync failure. How should I sync all missing data from my fake slave to my master, and what steps should I take?